# Get CSS Selector/Path of HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-selectors

I filtered the **HTML class elements** using

```
elements = document.querySelectorAll("div._3arMG")
```

Now that I have a list of HTML elements I need, I want the **CSS Selector/Path** for each HTML element in the `elements` list.

**CSS Selector** when I right click on HTML ELement in Console -> `Copy` -> `Copy Selector` -> `#root > div._3arMG`

**Please suggest how do I get this CSS Selector using Javascript?**

Answer (score 2):

You could use either `Element.querySelector()` or `Element.querySelectorAll()`, choose which suits your case

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("div._3arMG")

for (const element of elements){
  const subElements = element.querySelectorAll('.someclass')
  // or
  const subElement = element.querySelector('.someclass')
  
  // ... 
}
```

---

**Reference**

[Element.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)

[Element.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)

Comment: by `.someClass` , do you mean **unique id/class** for each HTML element in `elements`?

Comment: @SaiAvinashDuddupudi it queries all descendant elements which the selectors your defined, `.someclass` here is just example. If each descendant element has their own id, you could not need to query like this, in that case just use ` document.getElementById()` though. Correct me if I misunderstand what you said

Comment: `Element.queryseelctor()` doesnt return seelctor. did not get what you said

Answer (score 0):

You can do it recursivly with `parentElement` for the next node above. Getting for every node the tagname by `nodeName`, the classes with `classList` and the `id`.

**Edited:** Because Id's are unique I stop if an id occurs in the path.

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("div._3arMG");

let result = [];
elements.forEach(el => {
    result.push(getPath(el));
})
console.log(result);

function getPath(el) {
    let act = el.nodeName;
    el.classList.forEach(cl => act += '.' + cl);
    if (el.id) act += '#' + el.id;
        
    if (!el.id && el.parentElement) {
        let res = getPath(el.parentElement);
        res.push(act);
        return res;
    } else {
        return [act];
    }
}
```

```html
<div class='Wrapper'>
  <div class="_3arMG myClass">
    Test
  </div>
  <table id='myTable'>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="_3arMG">My span</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: As IDs *should* be unique, you could (possibly) stop when it hits an element with an id.

Comment: @freedomn-m - I suggested this too, but the OP shows us `-> Copy -> Copy Selector -> #root > div._3arMG` where the id `root`is in path so I build it complete.

Comment: "Copy -> Copy Selector" are the actions made in the browser :)   (not saying it's wrong to include the entire tree - bit hard to see what OP wants and why)

Comment: @freedomn-m - I changed itnow, after I see that this is really not part of the path ;)